# How to execute UNIX native command in Java?

Tags: java, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Unix shell script from java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)

I know you can use Runtime.exec() or a ProcessBuilder to execute native commands on windows in this way:

```
cmd /c command_goes_here
```

But what is the quivelant of this on UNIX?

Or will all commands work straight through Java?  Does it have internal terminal commands like Windows does?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out by yourself?

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code ?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562104/difference-between-running-internal-and-external-unix-commands-in-java ?

Comment: It's not quite the same, since OP wonders about screen control too.

Answer (score 0):

It's called `Runtime.exec()`.  That's sort of the point of Java -- write once run anywhere.

(Yes, yes, the same script won't run everywhere; that's what `Runtime` is for, to give you access to the underlying system.)

Java does *not*, however, have internal mechanisms for controlling the screen.  For that you need to resort of the usual AWT/SWT/Swing etc routines.

Comment: But... will using Runtime.exec() to run UNIX commands work for ALL UNIX commands?  Or are there commands that are internal to the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Java `exec` is based off of the Posix `exec*` calls.  So presumably you need to format the native command more or less the same way you'd do one in [Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) (though I don't know if you'd need to specify the command name twice like in Posix -- I've never tried Java `exec` under *nix).

The significant thing to note is that in *nix the individual commands like `ls` stand alone, whereas in Windows commands like `dir` are really just parameters to CMD.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, running `Runtime.exec()` will help you. But beware! there are several considerations to take into account for successfully running a command from Java. Be sure of reading [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) article first, it explains all you need to know.